# Run a python script from with arguments (from argparse in python) from crontab

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script which uses `argparse` and accepts a few arguments and run it from cron

example: `python test.py --a apple --b ball`

This needs to be scheduled from crontab .I can run it manually but cron fails to recognise the arguments .Please suggest solution.

The cron job line looks like :

```
* * * * * /pathtopython/python test.py --a apple --b ball > /tmp/abc.out 2>&1
```

Comment: Can you share with us what the cron line looks like?

Comment: * * * * * /pathtopython/python test.py --a apple --b ball > /tmp/abc.out 2>&1

Comment: The above is what it looks like and when i run it manually it runs fine

Answer (score 1):

`crontest.py` file code :

import argparse

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--a', help="First parameter")
parser.add_argument('--b', help="First parameter")
args = parser.parse_args()

file = open('/var/www/html/research/coding-challenge/geek.txt','a') 
file.write("This is the write command") 
file.write("It allows us to write in a particular file") 
file.write(args.a+args.b)

file.close()
```

Cron command :

```
*/1 * * * * python /var/www/html/crontest.py --a apple --b ballon
```

Important thing : dont forgot to restart cron in ubuntu.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

If you are using different os check for relevant command to restart cron.

Comment: Thanks for your input.I know the above and it works fine in command line but fails to run from cron.I was wondering if i was passing arguments correctly in the way cron expects it

Comment: cron is like running command only using crontab. This should works.

Comment: I know it should but it isn't :(

Comment: When i run it manually it runs fine,with cron it does not accept the arguments --a and --b

Comment: i tried */3 * * * * python /var/www/html/crontest.py apple22222 ball22222 its working fine. able to get parameters

Comment: Maybe i did not explain myself well - */3 * * * * python /var/www/html/crontest.py apple22222 ball22222 will work but when you use argpase in python you pass arguments like --argname so when i pass --a <value> it fails in that case

Comment: check my answer. you may be forgot to restart your cron. its working this code for me using cronjob.