# Python script doesn't execute via crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I read some similar topics but no luck to fix my issue.

This is my first Python script, it runs no problem when I manually execute it.

But it doesn't work with below crontab.

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.5/venv/send_email_attachment.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I also try to below.

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.5/venv/send_email_attachment.py > /tmp/listener.log >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The listener.log is generated but empty.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Don't throw the logs away with `>/dev/null 2>&1` – instead, look at the cron system logs to see the error. Your second attempt won't log anything into `/tmp/listener.log`, by the way, as you're redirecting standard output twice.

Comment: I tried `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.5/venv/send_email_attachment.py > /tmp/listener.log
`and `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.5/venv/send_email_attachment.py >/dev/null 2>&1
` and `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.5/venv/send_email_attachment.py` they all didn't execute by cron

Comment: Hi guys, I have figured out the issue, the script is designed to send an attachment, I have to the attached file a full path just like the script path, `/usr/lib/python3.5/venv/attachment` script and attachment are in same folder.

Answer (score 0):

The form of a cronjob is:

```
*  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

You forgot to add the user which runs the cronjob.
Supposing you run it using the root user, change the code to:

```
*/2 * * * * root /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.5/venv/send_email_attachment.py > /tmp/listener.log >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: It depends on which crontab you're looking at; if it's a user-specific crontab, there is no sixth column to specify the user.

Comment: I tried to add the username, but didn't work either, I have many PHP scripts, they all don't have the username included, they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:
`sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`

after setting crontab demon has to restart

Reference :[Run a python script from with arguments (from argparse in python) from crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175088/run-a-python-script-from-with-arguments-from-argparse-in-python-from-crontab/59175178#59175178)

Comment: I restarted a couple times, it still doesn't execute automatically...